# is there a way to stop a form from processing based on true or false using java script

Tags: javascript, forms

```
/*--------------------SUBMIT FORM -------------------*/
//Validate Form Fields
function FormValidation()
{
// validation fails if the input is blank
var verdba =document.getElementById('verdba').value;
if(verdba.value == "") {
  alert("Error: VERDBA FIRST!");
  verdba.focus();
  return false;
}

// validation was successful
return true;
processForm();
}



function processForm() {
// window.alert("processForm Reached"); // (Stub)
// Collect Values from the Form
// First section and verification

var callback = document.getElementById('callback').value;
var verdba = document.getElementById('verdba').value;
var comments = document.getElementById('comments').value;

// Concatenate the Page Content

var pageBody = " CB#:"+callback+" "+verdba+comments;

pageBody += "";

window.clipboardData.setData('Text',pageBody);



//Hides table on submit
$("#forms").hide();
    $(".myClass").hide();

//Copies pagebody to clipboard
var content = clipboardData.getData("Text");
document.forms["test"].elements["clipboard"].value = content;
}

// Hides table with clear button
function cleartable(){
$("#forms").hide();
    $(".myClass").hide();   
}
```

I have included a very bare bones example in a fiddle.

I noticed on the fiddle that it doesn't fully work but in the HTA I have it does work. What it does is `collects input fields` and `option fields` by `id`, concatenates them into what I call a note. It also copies the clipboard data to a text area.

What I want is to be able to click `submit` and have it collect the form data and check to see if two fields were used or not.

So in the `phone number field` I need to be sure a phone number is entered ( does not really matter to me if it checks that its a certain amount of digits or that it is digits at all as long as it isnt blank) and next check to see if the option box was selected, either yes or no, again not blank.

Upon discovering one or both were left blank or not selected I would like the process to stop and notify the user that it needs to be done. I would like it to give them a chance to fix it and then resubmit.

The problem I am having is that I can't get both to happen.

I have it where it collects the data and checks for the data, but the problem I ran into is that it doesnt care if its blank and you click ok, it still submits the request anyway and then clears the forms.

I just cant seem to figure out how to get both things working in one swing.

I hope someone can shed some light on this as it has been bugging me for days with endless online research and failed attempts.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshrt24/roqjoyhr/1/

Comment: return true;  processForm();    processForm will never get called, is that what you meant to do?

Comment: yeah i need to have the processForm called as long as the form  validation is true

Comment: I agree, you can't return something and the next line of code call a function.   `return true; processForm();` should be `processForm(); return true;`

Comment: So put the processForm, before your return.. return means exit the function and return value, any lines after it will never get run.

Comment: omg. that fixed it. I feel so stupid. thank you SO much

Comment: Please check the fiddle: I'm seeing `type="reset"` on the submit button, which clears the form without firing a submit event. Also consider creating a minimal test case to demonstrate the problem in the question.

Comment: i seen that too as im sitting here testing stuff and changed it to "button" and got it to work perfectly. Now if i can figure out how to mark this as answered....

Comment: @joshrt24  I think because there is no answer, you might not be able to mark it.  There was a lot of down-voter's on last night, so I think it just puts people off submitting answers, which is a shame.  I'll put an answer anyway, and then I think you can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function FormValidation(),

```
  // validation was successful
  return true;
  processForm();
}
```

You have put return true, before your function has chance to call the processForm, return will immediately exit your function.

Fix, just call processForm() first.

```
  // validation was successful
  processForm();
  return true;      
}
```